# probability calculator with factorial equation

Tags: c++, probability, factorial

I have to make a code that calculates the probability of winning the lottery given the amount of numbers there are to choose from and how many you must choose. I must use the factorial equation `(n!)/(k!*(n-k)!)` in the code. The code itself works fine, but the equation will not compile.

```
//This program calculates the probability of winning the lottery
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double factorial(int n, int k);

int main()
{
    //variables
    int n;
    int k;
    char pa;
    int chance;
    double prob;

    //loop
    do
    {

        cout << "How many numbers (1-12) are there to pick from?\n" << endl;
        cin >> n;

        if(n>12 || n<1)
        {
            cout << "Invalid entry.\nHow many numbers (1-12) are there to pick from?\n";
            cin >> n;
        }

        cout << "How many numbers must you pick to play?\n";
        cin >> k;

        if(k>n || k<1)
        {
            cout << "Invalid entry.\nHow many numbers must you pick to play?\n";
            cin >> n;
        }

        cout << "Your chance of winning the lottery is 1 in " << chance << endl;
        prob=factorial( n, k);
        cout << "This is a probability of " << prob << endl;
        cout << "Play again?";
        cin >> pa;
    } while (pa != 'n');

    return 0;
}

double factorial(int n, int k)
{
    double fact;

    fact=(n!)/(k!*(n-k)!);
    return fact;
}
```

Comment: Your function `factorial` does not even calculate the factorial even if your code did work. write a function factorial that calculates n! and use that within another function to calculate the probability. The formula you have in your `factorial` function would calculate a binomial coefficient (if it compiled)

Comment: Not C code... removing tag.

Answer (score 1):

There is no **!** operator in C++ in the meaning of a factorial operation, and your `factorial` function is not calculating a factorial. (The **!** operator is typically a logical **NOT** operator.)

This is how one would write a factorial method,

```
int factorial(int n) {
  return (n <= 1 ? 1 : n * factorial(n - 1));
}
```

<sub>The method is recursive and is operating on integers - you may need to consider whether this is suitable for your task</sub>

Then your original function should be renamed along the lines of `double choice(int n, int k)` and use the new `factorial` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write `n!` and expect it to calculate the factorial of `n`.

Change `fact=(n!)/(k!*(n-k)!)` to `fact=f(n)/(f(k)*f(n-k))`, and add the following function:

```
unsigned long long f(int n)
{
    unsigned long long res = 1;
    while (n > 1)
    {
        res *= n;
        n--;
    }
    return res;
}
```

BTW, you have several other problems within your code:

1. You are using variable `chance` without initializing it.
2. Function `factorial` does not return the probability, but the number of different choices. This is an integer value, and you might as well use `unsigned long long` instead of `double` for it. The probability is the inverse of the value (`1/value`), so you should change your printed message accordingly.